# Find m.g.f. given $E(X^r)$ function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

> "Let $X$ be a random variable with $E(X^r) = 1 / (1 + r)$, where $r = 1, 2, 3,\ldots,n$. Find the series representation for the m.g.f. of $X$, $M(t)$. Sum this series. Identify (name) the probability distribution of $X$?

As a hint, use the Taylor Formula."

The expectation is what is throwing me off here. So it's a summation? The summation doesn't converge, and I'm not aware of how to get the mgf without knowing the distribution or pdf/cdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *definition* of mgf is

$$
M(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]
$$
and so
$$
E[X^r] = M^{(r)}(0).
$$

Notice that if we represent $M(t)$ as a McLaurin series, say
$$
M(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{m_n}{n!} t^n
$$
then $M^{(n)}(0) = \frac{m_n}{n!}$. We can now equate them, getting
$m_n = \frac{n!}{1+n}$ and so
$$
M(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{m_n}{n!} t^n
     = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{1+n}.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I can do the summation - I get `-(ln(1-t))/t` . I can't find a distribution that has a mgf like this, however. Did I do the summation wrong?

Comment: @SheerSt Wolfram Alpha seems to agree with your Taylor series: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Taylor+Series%5B+-Log%5B1-t%5D%5D -- to find the distribution, remember that
$$
M(t) = \mathbb{E} \left[ e^{tX} \right]
     = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{tx} f(x) dx
$$
so you must find such a pdf $f(x)$ that satisfies the integral equation
$$
\frac{\ln(1-t}{-t} = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{tx} f(x) dx.
$$
No time to think more, but the RHS is the Laplace transform of $f(x)$, can you perhaps take the inverse Laplace transform of the LHS to get $f(x)$?